# How to remove comma from digits in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a requirement from client side and I am not able to find the file path.
My client want to remove "Commas" from digits.
My question is this, in which file this text exist. I want to know file path where i can make changes.
Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: That might be result of function [number_format_i18n](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/number_format_i18n/)

Comment: If you're trying to change the localisation in the admin area, I would assume it's to do with your WP localisation settings - I certainly don't recommend you go looking for the code to change in the WP core files! Questions about WordPress administration & configuration, etc. are off topic here and are more suited to the [dedicated WordPress Development Stack Exchange site](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com).  However please review their help section first before posting to make sure your question meets their guidelines.